# Is it possible to unit test C macros for embedded software?

Tags: c, unit-testing, macros, avr

I was how it's possible to test some specific C macros for embedded SW.

For example if I have the following macro:

```
/*
Set a pin as an input
port  (B,C, D or E) 
pin  - pin to set (0-7)
*/
#define _SET_INPUT_PIN(port,pin) DDR ## port &= ~(1<<pin)
#define SET_INPUT_PIN(...) _SET_INPUT_PIN(__VA_ARGS__)
```

and I want to test it with two ports, one who exists (LED_OK) the other one no (LED_FAIL):

```
#define LED_OK   D,3
#define LED_FAIL D,8
```

When I try to test it both LED_OK and LED_FAIL will work fine but some sort of warning/fail should alert that LED_FAIL doesn't exist since PORTD has only defined pins 0 to 7.

So, when I pass a *LED* how could I check "*pin*" is in range?

Comment: Probably you missed that the preprocessing is only a kind of text substitution, no checks are made. Moreover the generated C code leads to a simple `and` assignment, an operation that don't requires any check, so no warning will be issued unless you add checks in your macro. The best solution is to use an `assert` on the pin number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is way too obscure. In general, I would strongly recommend *not* to hide super-trivial stuff like setting/clearing a pin behind abstraction layers.

Instead you should write something like:

```
#define LED_DDR  DDRD
#define LED_PORT PORTD
#define LED_PIN  (1u << 3)

LED_DDR  |= LED_PIN;  // set pin to output
LED_PORT |= LED_PIN;  // set pin to 1
LED_PORT &= ~LED_PIN; // set pin to 0
LED_PORT &= (uint8_t)~LED_PIN; // set pin to 0 with pedantic type safety (MISRA-C etc)
LED_PORT ^= LED_PIN;  // toggle pin
```

You can't really write clearer code so any abstraction layer beyond this is doomed to fail. It will not add clarity but it may add bugs. As seen from some thousands sketchy attempts on the SO/EE sites where people attempt to do just that. Or as seen in bloatware libs from silicon vendors.

---

A proper test would thus not test the obscure macro `SET_INPUT_PIN` but question its existence. The name of the test is code review. Which would also point out the following issues:

- There's absolutely no need to make this a variadic macro since it should accept exactly 2 arguments - not more, not less. This is nothing but sheer obfuscation.
- There is no type safety provided by this macro. The caller could literally pass anything to it and there's a big chance to silently pass compilation.
- Identifiers starting with an underscore, then followed by an upper case letter are reserved for libraries. So don't name macros `_S` etc, it might collide with the compiler libraries.
- The macro is naively written. The average coding standard out there will enforce something like `( (DDR ## port) &= ~(1 <<(pin)) )` with parenthesis both around macro parameters as well as around the final expression.
- The macro is using `1` signed integer constants which becomes a major hazard soon as we expand to 16 bit registers on what is likely a system with 16 bit `int`. We'll then get undefined behavior bugs all over the place. Should have been `1u`.
- There's implicit promotion so the macro actually returns a 16 bit negative value `int`. Which is unhelpful and dangerous.

Comment: Agree with the approach in this answer. This is how I would do it as well. Or implement `set_pin` as a function where you can do all the sanity checking you want. Most decent compilers would inline such trivial functions anyway.

Comment: @th33lf I'd start to ask myself why I expect someone to set the wrong pin number to begin with. That is, what's the problem I wish to prevent: clumsy programmers, or runaway code, or memory corruption? The methods for dealing with these very separate problems are very different. Sanity checks/defensive programming does make sense to stop runaway code, but they don't make much sense if the purpose is to prevent programmers from typing the wrong numbers.

Comment: Maybe not for a trivial use-case like this, but when you are writing HALs (hardware abstraction layers) that are meant to be used for many products with different pinouts and ports, even from different manufacturers. You can expect someone to try to use a non-existent pin and you could check for it based on the data from a device-specific configuration file. So you just say something like `gpio_setpin(indicator_led.port, indicator_led.pin)` and it is neatly abstracted. But the usefulness can be contested of course and a runtime check would affect performance as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's really well explained.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible to be done at compile time. You cannot use say, a `#if` inside of a macro substitution.

You can technically pass anything to the two arguments of `_SET_INPUT_PIN`. They are just blindly substituted by the pre-processor wherever they occur in the macro definition. You may pass constants to these, but they can also be variables. If it is a variable then it has no meaning at compile time since variables exist only at run-time. So there is no way of implementing this check at compile time. You can of course, implement a run-time check.

For example,

```
/*
Set a pin as an input
port  (B,C, D or E) 
pin  - pin to set (0-7)
*/
#define _SET_INPUT_PIN(port,pin) \do \
{ \
    if (pin < 8) \
        DDR ## port &= ~(1<<pin); \
    else \
        fail();\
}while(0)
```

Comment: Well, it's perfectly possible to do this at compile time. Just for reference, you could `_Static_assert((uint8_t)(pin) < 8, "Wrong pin number")`. But that's not the right solution either, the right solution is to nuke the entire macro.

Comment: Static assert will not allow a variable as the pin number. Besides, you assume C11 or above which is not usually the case with 8-bit AVR compilers, which is what this looks like to me. Agree that I wouldn't use a macro at all though!

Comment: Any decent microcontroller compiler supports C11 since forever. If someone is insisting on using some old crap, then that's an unrelated problem. But then AVR itself is old crap to begin with, so I guess you have a point - the only reason why anyone would use it today is when maintaining old products.

Answer (score 0):

Following what I sai in the comment above you can try using an `assert()` in your macro:

```
/*
    Set a pin as an input
    port  (B,C, D or E) 
    pin  - pin to set (0-7)
*/
#define _SET_INPUT_PIN(port,pin) do {                            \
                                       assert(pin>=0 && pin<8);  \
                                       DDR ## port &= ~(1<<pin); \
                                    }  while(0)
#define SET_INPUT_PIN(port, pin) _SET_INPUT_PIN(port, pin)
```

The `assert` checks the condition and produce an error. If compiling in C11, you can use the `_Static_assert(condition, message)` that checks the conditions just after macro expansion, and works as a macro control.

```
#define _SET_INPUT_PIN(port,pin) do {                            \
                                       _Static_assert(pin>=0 && pin<8, "Bad pin");  \
                                       DDR ## port &= ~(1<<pin); \
                                    }  while(0)
```

Please note also the use of parameters instead of the variable arguments that can lead to more errors.

Comment: No. Use static asserts. Or better yet, don't write macros like this to begin with.

Comment: Also you've added another big, subtle macro bug on top of the others. `if (x) SET_INPUT_PIN(D, 3)`. Oops. Yet another perfect illustration why we shouldn't write abstraction layers around simple GPIO.

Comment: @Lundin I was adding the `_Static_assert` while you commented out. I don't really get the second comment about the macro bug.

Comment: When using my example and your code, then pre-processed: `if(x) assert(); /* new line */ DDRD &= ~(1<<3); // oops, it always gets set no matter if(x)`

Comment: So you need to use the old do-while(0) trick. Or better yet, don't use it but use `{ }`. See [What is do { } while(0) in macros and should we use it?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/279576).

Comment: I used the do-while(0) in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67415903/3214247

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the link, but I'm old enough to know about `{}` and `do{}while(0);`, anyway thanks for the point I intended a simple answer. Anyway I still surprise myself for such big efforts on really simple questions, they require so much time that makes you ask yourself 'Why I answered?".